# Getting value of first index within jQuery array using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a JSON array returned via ajax that looks like:

`"stuff": [["2","66%"], ["3","42%"],...`

**Problem**
I want to match the zeroth index of each element in this array to a variable outside of the loop and if it matches, I want to return the percentage next to it.

I don't know the syntax in jQuery for this. Please have a look at my code below and see if that's correct or not:

```
var percentage = 0;
var stuffarr = jsonobj['stuff'];
var stuffID = jsonobj['stuff_id']
if (!stuffID || 0 === stuffID.length){
   $("#stuff-element").html("--");
}
else {
   var percentage = $.each(stuffarr, function (index, value) {
   if(value[0] == stuffID)
      return value[1]   
   });
}
```

Comment: What is var stuffID = jsonobj['stuff_id']. Is this another array?

Comment: It's a string number, e.g. `"2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a bit of terminology. The data structure you have is an Object which holds several properties. It has nothing to do with JSON after it has been deserialised.

With regard to your issue, there's no jQuery required as you can use `find()` to find the item in the array by the `stuffID` variable's value. Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  "stuff": [
    ["2", "66%"],
    ["3", "42%"]
  ],
  "stuff_id": "3"
}

var percentage = 0;
var stuffArr = obj['stuff'];
var stuffId = obj['stuff_id']

if (!stuffId || 0 === stuffId.length) {
  $("#stuff-element").html("--");
} else {
  percentage = stuffArr.find(function(el) {
    return el[0] == stuffId;
  })[1];
}
  
console.log(percentage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could use the find method as you only want to return one

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen you're right - thanks. I'd misread the question and though the OP would possibly be searching for multiple.

Comment: Also, my bad but I think I shouldn't have re-initialised the `percentage` variable inside the else statement

Comment: @omrakhur yep, you should only define `var percentage` at the outer scope. I missed that too. Having a slow morning :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var percentage = stuffarr.find(function (value) {
if(value[0] == stuffID)
   return value[1];  
})[1];
```

Comment: Owen, your answer works fine as well, however Rory added a bit of an explanation, so I have accepted that as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: That is fair enough

Answer (score 0):

The return statement you used returns the result of the function(..) inside the .each(..) function and is not the return value of the .each(..) function.
the valid return value is boolean which 'tells' the .each(..) function whether it should continue or not. instead use the following syntax:

```
var ret = '';
$(arr).each(function () {
    var curr = $(this);
    //console.log(curr); 
    if(curr[0] == stuffID){
        //console.log('>>found: ' + curr[1]);
        ret = curr[1];
        //if found -> break loop
        return false; 
    }
});
```

comment: you should consider instead of using an inner array data structure use an object, this is a more 'correct' data structure:

```
// "stuff": [{"id":"2","percent":"66%"}, {"id":"3","percent":"42%"},...
var ret = '';
$(arr).each(function () {
    var curr = this;
    //console.log(curr.id); 
    if(curr.id == stuffID){
        //console.log('>>found: ' + curr.percent);
        ret = curr.percent;
        //if found -> break loop
        return false; 
    }
});
```

@LiverpoolOwen approach is clean and nice, and if you want to use it combining with the object approach do this:

```
arr.find(function (value) {
if(value.id == stuffID)
   return value;  
}).percent;
```